# why i cant list the golang package version

Tags: go

i check the package with git list

```
go list -m -versions github.com/vladimirvivien/go4vl
github.com/vladimirvivien/go4vl v0.0.0-alpha v0.0.1
```

the package  has  2 vesison :

- v0.0.0-alpha
- v0.0.1

the result is same as from

https://github.com/vladimirvivien/go4vl/tags
.

but device-usb-camera use a package verion of following:

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/wubigo/device-usb-camera.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/wubigo/device-usb-camera.git (push)

go list -m all | grep  github.com/vladimirvivien/go4vl | awk '{print $2}'
v0.0.2-0.20211216162907-40b41ba86c5c
```

why i can't see the version of  v0.0.2-0.20211216162907-40b41ba86c5c?

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

use the commit id of 40b41ba as the pkg version

```
go get github.com/vladimirvivien/go4vl@40b41ba
go get: upgraded github.com/vladimirvivien/go4vl v0.0.1 => v0.0.2-0.20211216162907-40b41ba86c5c
```

https://deepsource.io/blog/go-modules/#which-version-is-pulled-by-default